# Flutter: Cannot see directory created in app document directory through the file browser in android

Tags: android, flutter

I use the below flutter code to create the directory **ABC** inside the app document directory in android. When it runs for the 1st time, it prints 'Project Dir Created' and 2nd time onwards 'Project Dir Exist'.
But through the file browser in the emulator, I cannot see created directory.
It just shows only the **files** directory inside **/data/user/0/com.example.test_app/** directory. No other directory is visible inside the **/data/user/0/com.example.test_app/** directory. Even the app document directory (**app_flutter**) is not visible inside it.

```
final Directory _appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final String _appDocPath = _appDocDir.path;
final Directory _prjDir = Directory('$_appDocPath/ABC');
if (await _prjDir.exists()) {
    print('Project Dir Exist');
} else {
    final Directory _prjDirCreated = await _prjDir.create(recursive: true);
    print('Project Dir Created');
}
```

Is it expected? If so, is there any way to see the file created inside the app document directory while doing the flutter developments?

Comment: Your application's document directory isn't supposed to be accessible to a normal user outside of your app (or other apps or system apps like Gallery). You can view the contents in an adb shell by executing `run-as com.Your.App` then cd to the folder and ls the contents.

Comment: `It just shows only the files directory inside /data/user/0/com.example.test_app/` We do not believe that. No other app has access to that private directory of your app. The device browser of Android Studio can.

Comment: @blackapps Where can I find the device browser in Android Studio (InteliJ) for a flutter project

Comment: Where it is normally. I think it has nothing to do with Flutter.

Comment: @blackapps then how can we use those stored files?

Comment: What is it that you wanna do with them? Looks like a new question.